# Antlr Sample Grammar Error

Tags: antlr

I am new to ANTLR, I defined the following test grammar, it's basically intended to parse a series of assignment statement like the following

```
x=1
y=10
```

=======================================================================

```
grammar test;

program
    :
        assignstatement*
    ;

assignstatement
    :
        ID '=' INT   
    ;

ID : ('_'|'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|DIGIT) ('_'|'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|DIGIT)*;

INT: DIGIT+;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ; // not a token by itself
```

I got the following error when running the testRig

```
[@0,0:0='x',<1>,1:0]
[@1,2:2='=',<3>,1:2]
[@2,4:4='1',<1>,1:4]
[@3,7:7='y',<1>,2:0]
[@4,9:9='=',<3>,2:2]
[@5,11:12='10',<1>,2:4]
[@6,14:13='<EOF>',<-1>,3:0]
line 1:4 missing INT at '1'
line 2:0 extraneous input 'y' expecting '='
line 2:4 missing INT at '10'
line 3:0 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting '='

(program (assignstatement x = <missing INT>) (assignstatement 1 y = <missing INT>) (assignstatement 10))
```

Can someone figure out what's causing these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lexer will never create `INT` tokens because your `ID` rule also matches tokens consisting of only digits.

Let your `ID` rule *not* be able start with a digit, and you're fine:

```
ID : ('_'|'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('_'|'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|DIGIT)*;
```

Or the equivalent:

```
ID : [_a-zA-Z] [_a-zA-Z0-9]*;
```